# Moving and renaming files recursively

Tags: macos, bash, mac, terminal, shell

I have the following file structure:

```
root
root/year
root/year/MM-Month
root/year/MM-Month/YYMMTT_Event
root/year/MM-Month/YYMMTT_Event/01 Photos/
root/year/MM-Month/YYMMTT_Event/01 Screenshots/
root/year/MM-Month/YYMMTT_Event/02 Video/
root/year/MM-Month/YYMMTT_Event/Template.txt
root/year/MM-Month/YYMMTT_Event/File.xy2z.jpg
root/year/MM-Month/YYMMTT_Event/File.xy3z.jpeg
root/year/MM-Month/YYMMTT_Event/File.xy3z.nef
root/year/MM-Month/YYMMTT_Event/File.xy2z.raw
root/year/MM-Month/YYMMTT_Event/File.xyz2.png
root/year/MM-Month/YYMMTT_Event/File.xyz2.mov
root/year/MM-Month/YYMMTT_Event/File.xyz2.mpeg
```

1. I would like to rename all Template.txt files to `YYMMTT_Event.txt` recursively.
2. I would like to move all photos: `jpg, jpeg, nef, raw ...` to the `01 Photos folder`.
3. I would like to move all screenshots: `png, gif` to the `01 Screenshots` folder.
4. I would like to move all videos: `mov, mpeg` to the `02 Video` folder.

What's the easiest way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A loop. or find or both.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s extglob nullglob

while IFS= read -r -d '' file ; do
  if [[ $file == *Template.txt && -f $file ]]; then
    temp="${file%/*}"
    echo mv -v "$file" "${file%/*}/${temp##*/}.txt"
  elif [[ $file == *Photos* && -d $file ]]; then
    Photordir=$file
  elif [[ $file == *Screenshots* && -d $file ]]; then
    Screendir=$file
  elif [[ $file == *Video* && -d $file ]]; then
    Videodir=$file
  elif [[ $file == *.@(jpg|jpeg|nef|raw) && -f $file ]]; then
    echo mv -v "$file" "$Photordir"
  elif [[ $file == *.@(png|gif) && -f $file ]]; then
    echo mv -v "$file" "$Screendir"
  elif [[ $file == *.@(mov|mpeg) && -f $file ]]; then
    echo mv -v "$file" "$Videodir"
  fi
done < <(find . -print0)
```

Output

- Change the `.` to `find` to the correct directory, It is the current directory.
  e.g. `find /path/to/directory ....`
- Remove all the `echo` so it can do it's job.
- I may need some more error checking, code refactoring but it is left as an exercise for you

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you could call a renaming script from the `root` directory:

```bsh
[gnubeard@mothership: ~/root]$ tree
.
└── year
    └── MM-Month
        └── YYMMTT_Event
            ├── 01 Photos
            ├── 01 Screenshots
            ├── 02 Video
            ├── File.xy2z.jpg
            ├── File.xy2z.raw
            ├── File.xy3z.jpeg
            ├── File.xy3z.nef
            ├── File.xyz2.mov
            ├── File.xyz2.mpeg
            ├── File.xyz2.png
            └── Template.txt

6 directories, 8 files
[gnubeard@mothership: ~/root]$ find . -maxdepth 4 -type f -exec ~/renamer {} \;
[gnubeard@mothership: ~/root]$ tree
.
└── year
    └── MM-Month
        └── YYMMTT_Event
            ├── 01 Photos
            │   ├── File.xy2z.jpg
            │   ├── File.xy2z.raw
            │   ├── File.xy3z.jpeg
            │   └── File.xy3z.nef
            ├── 01 Screenshots
            │   └── File.xyz2.png
            ├── 02 Video
            │   ├── File.xyz2.mov
            │   └── File.xyz2.mpeg
            └── YYMMTT_Event.txt

6 directories, 8 files
```

Here's an example of a little renaming script that you can easily expand to handle arbitrary filetypes.

```bsh
#! /usr/bin/env bash
DIRNAME=$(dirname "$1")
PARENTNAME=$(basename "$DIRNAME")
case $(basename "$1") in
  Template.txt)
    mv "$1" "${DIRNAME}/${PARENTNAME}.txt"
    ;;
  "${PARENTNAME}.txt") # Prevents attempted handling of YYMMTT_Event.txt
    ;;
  *.jpg|*.jpeg|*.nef|*.raw)
    mv "$1" "${DIRNAME}/01 Photos/"
    ;;
  *.png|*.gif)
    mv "$1" "${DIRNAME}/01 Screenshots/"
    ;;
  *.mov|*.mpeg)
    mv "$1" "${DIRNAME}/02 Video/"
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Unhandled filetype for $1"
    ;;
esac
```